# Only the url changes when i click Back in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

```
import {Router} from "@angular/router";

constructor(private router: Router){}

this.router.navigate(['/'], {
        queryParams: {
            myQueryParam: 'test'
        }
    });
```

when i click my item this router changes my url to localhost:3000/?myQueryParam=test

But only the url changes when i click browser back button.

how can i back to previous url without enter click

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this to go to previous page ::

```
import {Location} from '@angular/common';

constructor(private _location: Location) { }

goBack(){
    this._location.back();
  }
```

You have to just add this five line of code and you can go to the previous page.

Comment: Its working fine from my side. Can you add plunker so I can see what is the problem ?

Comment: and https://run.plnkr.co/preview/cjciu0n4b00083b5wlh1ybhbi/?body=body1
body doesn't change when back button click

Comment: use onbeforeunload or ngondestroy method , it might can help

Comment: https://run.plnkr.co/UvXussKBLkaU7jaU/
this site will show , What should I do with ngondestroy?

Comment: First of all in your plunker you are using only one component. So when you clicked back button then component remain same so that,s why your data is not changing. If you want to change the data you should use different component and provide routing between them and then when you navigate back last component will be load. For only one component you can use ngOnInit but whenever you pressed back button then your ngOnInit will call and initial data will be loaded. So my suggestion is to use different component and provide routing to navigate through.